# Let $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(1)=2011$ and $f(n)= \frac{1}{n^2 -1}(f(1)+f(2)+...+f(n-1))$ for $n \ge 2$. Calculate $f(2011)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Being $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(1)=2011$ and $f(n)=  \frac{1}{n^2 -1}(f(1)+f(2)+...+f(n-1))$ for $n \ge 2$. Calculate $f(2011)$

When calculating $f(n)$ I need to consider the sum of the previous elements, from $2011$ to $f(n-1)$. But when considering each of these, I need again the the sum of the previous $f(n)$. I've never met a problem like this. It seems like a sequence  by recursion: are there any rules when approaching problems like this?

Comment: $f(2) = 2011/3 \notin \Bbb N$, which means that there is no such function.

Comment: As for how to approach a problem like this, compute the first few values of $f$ and try to see a pattern. If you come up with a guess for a formula for $f(n)$ there's likely a straightforward proof by induction that it's correct.

Comment: @MartinR I’ve noticed that but the text is correct

Comment: Then the answer is just “there is no such function.”

Answer (score 3):

Hint: let $g(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n f(k)$. Then we have $f(2011) = g(2011) - g(2010)$ and

$$g(n) = g(n-1) + f(n)$$

$$g(n) = g(n-1) + \frac{1}{n^2 - 1}g(n-1)$$

$$g(n) = \frac{n^2}{n^2 - 1}g(n-1)$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! But knowing $g(n)$ if I calculate $f(2011)$ as $g(2011)-g(2010)$ it goes back to the initial $f(n)$. Am I wrong? Another hint?

Comment: @Futurballa I don't understand your question. If you can find out a formula for $g(n)$ based on my hint you can  calculate $g(2011)$ and $g(2010)$ and subtract them to find $f(2011)$.